# How to convert a String (numeric) in a Int array in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, int

I'd like to know how can I convert a String in an Int array in Swift.
In Java I've always done it like this:

```
String myString = "123456789";
int[] myArray = new int[myString.lenght()];
for(int i=0;i<myArray.lenght;i++){
   myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(myString.charAt(i));
}
```

Thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: I'm removing the `java` tag, since this question isn't actually about Java.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
let str = "123456789"
let intArray = map(str) { String($0).toInt() ?? 0 }
```

- `map()` iterates `Character`s in `str`
- `String($0)` converts `Character` to `String`
- `.toInt()` converts `String` to `Int`. If failed(`??`), use `0`.

If you prefer `for` loop, try:

```
let str = "123456789"
var intArray: [Int] = []

for chr in str {
    intArray.append(String(chr).toInt() ?? 0)
}
```

OR, if you want to iterate indices of the `String`:

```
let str = "123456789"
var intArray: [Int] = []

for i in indices(str) {
    intArray.append(String(str[i]).toInt() ?? 0)
}
```

Comment: `toInt()` is no longer available in `String` in Swift 2.x.

Answer (score 19):

You can use flatMap to convert the characters into a string and coerce the character strings into an integer:

**Swift 2 or 3**

```
let string = "123456789"
let digits = string.characters.flatMap{Int(String($0))}
print(digits)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
```

**Swift 4**

```
let string = "123456789"
let digits = string.flatMap{Int(String($0))}
print(digits)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
```

**Swift 4.1**

```
let digits = string.compactMap{Int(String($0))}
```

**Swift 5 or later**

We can use the new Character Property `wholeNumberValue` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127025-wholenumbervalue

```
let digits = string.compactMap{$0.wholeNumberValue}
```

**Swift 5.2 or later** [Key Path Expressions as Functions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0249-key-path-literal-function-expressions.md)

```
let digits = string.compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue)
```

Comment: Swift 4.1 deprecates `.flatMap` for this use case. Use `.compactMap` instead: `let digits = string.compactMap{Int(String($0))}`

Comment: `let digits = string.compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue)` is also a nice way to write it (Swift 5)

Comment: @JKvr yes it is called keyPath https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415964/2303865 Swift 5.2 or later. It is not available for Swift 5.0

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Int array to String

```
let arjun = [1,32,45,5]
    print(self.get_numbers(array: arjun))

 func get_numbers(array:[Int]) -> String {
        let stringArray = array.flatMap { String(describing: $0) }
        return stringArray.joined(separator: ",")
```

String to Int Array

```
let arjun = "1,32,45,5"
    print(self.get_numbers(stringtext: arjun))

    func get_numbers(stringtext:String) -> [Int] {
    let StringRecordedArr = stringtext.components(separatedBy: ",")
    return StringRecordedArr.map { Int($0)!}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@rintaro's answer is correct, but I just wanted to add that you can use `reduce` to weed out any characters that can't be converted to an `Int`, and even display a warning message if that happens:

```
let str = "123456789"
let intArray = reduce(str, [Int]()) { (var array: [Int], char: Character) -> [Int] in
    if let i = String(char).toInt() {
        array.append(i)
    } else {
        println("Warning: could not convert character \(char) to an integer")
    }
    return array
}
```

The advantages are:

- if `intArray` contains zeros you will know that there was a `0` in `str`, and not some other character that turned into a zero
- you will get told if there is a non-`Int` character that is possibly screwing things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "123456789"
var myArray:[Int] = []

for index in 0..<countElements(myString) {
    var myChar = myString[advance(myString.startIndex, index)]
    myArray.append(String(myChar).toInt()!)
}

println(myArray)   // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
```

To get the `iterator` pointing to a `char` from the `string` you can use `advance`

The method to convert `string` to `int` in Swift is `toInt()`

Comment: You have a loop in your loop—calling `advance` over and over like that is a bad idea, since you're making the program step through the string from the beginning each time.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 update:

@appzYourLife : That's correct `toInt()` method is no longer available for String in Swift 3.
As an alternative what you can do is :

```
intArray.append(Int(String(chr)) ?? 0)
```

Enclosing it within `Int()` converts it to Int.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3: Functional Approach

1. Split the `String` into separate `String` instances using:
   `components(separatedBy separator: String) -> [String]`

> Reference: Returns an array containing substrings from the String that have been divided by a given separator.

2. Use the `flatMap` `Array` method to bypass the `nil` coalescing while converting to `Int`

> Reference: Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given transformation with each element of this sequence.

**Implementation**

```
let string = "123456789"
let intArray = string.components(separatedBy: "").flatMap { Int($0) }
```

Comment: Swift 4.1 deprecates `.flatMap` for this use case. Instead, use `.compactMap`: `let intArray = string.components(separatedBy: "").compactMap { Int($0) }`

Comment: @leanne this is wrong it would result in an array with a single element of the same value of the input `[123456789]`. The first method  `components(separatedBy: "")` would result in a single string element `["123456789"]`

Comment: I simply replaced the deprecated `.flatMap` with the new `.compactMap`, @LeoDabus. Both results are the same. As printed in Xcode's debug console: `[123456789]` and `[123456789]`. Note that I am not judging whether the result is appropriate for the original question, but simply remarking for anyone who comes here that `.flatMap` has been deprecated in favor of `.compactMap` in cases where one is attempting to achieve a result that removes `nil` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = "0123456789".compactMap{ Int(String($0)) }
print(array)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.