# How to split an Int to its individual digits?

Tags: swift

I am trying to split an Int into its individual digits, e.g. 3489 to 3 4 8 9, and then I want to put the digits in an Int array.

I have already tried putting the number into a string and then iterating over each digit, but it doesn't work:

```
var number = "123456"

var array = [Int]()

for digit in number {
    array.append(digit)
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

We can also extend the StringProtocol and create a computed property:

edit/update: **Xcode 11.5 • Swift 5.2**

```
extension StringProtocol  {
    var digits: [Int] { compactMap(\.wholeNumberValue) }
}
```

---

```
let string = "123456"
let digits = string.digits // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}

extension Numeric where Self: LosslessStringConvertible {
    var digits: [Int] { string.digits }
}
```

---

```
let integer = 123
let integerDigits = integer.digits // [1, 2, 3]

let double = 12.34
let doubleDigits = double.digits   // // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

In **Swift 5** now we can use the new `Character` property `wholeNumberValue`

```
let string = "123456"

let digits = string.compactMap{ $0.wholeNumberValue } // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Leonardo! Also what if i wanted to split numbers that they were in an array? e.g var array=[456, 827]

Comment: is it going to return an array with 6 Ints or 2 arrays of 3 Ints ?

Comment: it will return 1 array 6 Ints

Comment: Try this: 
`let nestedInts = [123, 456]; nestedInts.flatMap{$0.array}` Should give you: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: flatMap has been renamed as compactMap in Swift 4.2

Answer (score 8):

A solution without having to convert the int to string....

Example

```
1234%10 = 4 <-
1234/10 = 123
123%10 = 3 <-
123/10 = 12
12%10 = 2 <- 
12/10 = 1
1%10 = 1 <-

var num = 12345
var arrayInt = [Int]()
arrayInt.append(num%10)
while num >= 10 {
  num = num/10
  arrayInt.insert(num%10, at: 0)
}
```

Comment: Did you try this on the number 10 or anything that starts with 10? `num = 10` appends `0`. The check `num > 10` will be `false` and the array will be missing the leading `1`

Comment: You'll want to use the absolute value here incase the number is negative, `abs(number)`.

Comment: I was trying to find Palindrome number. But this formula doesn't work for negative numbers. For example -121.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

```swift
extension Int {
    func digits() -> [Int] {
        var digits: [Int] = []
        var num = self
        
        digits.append(num % 10)
        
        while num >= 10  {
            num = num / 10
            digits.append(num % 10)
        }
        
        return digits.reversed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
var number = "123456"
var array = number.utf8.map{Int($0)-48}
```

You can make use of the `utf8` property of `String` to directly access the ASCII value of the characters in the String representation of your number.

Answer (score 4):

**if you need convert integer to Array**

```
let num = 12345
let array = String(num).compactMap({$0.wholeNumberValue})
print("\(array), \(type(of: array))")
//[1,2,3,4,5], Array<Int>
```

Answer (score 3):

this code works:

```
var number = "123456"
var array = number.utf8.map{Int(($0 as UInt8)) - 48}
```

this might be slower:

```
var array = number.characters.map{Int(String($0))!}
```

and if your number is less or equal than Int.max  which is 9223372036854775807 here is the fastest variant (and if your number>Int.max you can split your long string that represents your number into 18-digit groups to make this variant work on large strings)

```
var array2 = [Int]()
var i = Int(number)!
while i > 0 {array2.append(i%10); i/=10}
array2 = array2.reverse()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
extension Int {

func numberOfDigits() -> Int {
    if abs(self) < 10 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return 1 + (self/10).numberOfDigits()
    }
}

func getDigits() -> [Int] {
    let num = self.numberOfDigits()
    var tempNumber = self
    var digitList = [Int]()

    for i in (0..<num).reversed() {
        let divider = Int(pow(CGFloat(10), CGFloat(i)))
        let digit = tempNumber/divider
        digitList.append(digit)
        tempNumber -= digit*divider
    }
    return digitList
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```swift
extension Int {
    var digits : [Int] {
        var result = [Int]()
        var remaining = abs(self)
        while remaining > 0 {
            result.insert(remaining % 10, at: 0)
            remaining /= 10
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply append each digit and return the result reversed()

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler method to achieve this. Say `x = 12345` , then

```
var s = String(x);
var numArray = Array(s);
```

clean, easy-to-read code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
let number = -123
let regex = /-?\d/
let values = String(number).matches(of: regex).compactMap { Int($0.output) }
print(values) // [-1, 2, 3]
```

This code takes into account negative values

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
// input -> "123456"
// output -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
// Get the string, convert it in an Array(), 
// use a loop (convert i in Int()), to add it into a container, then return it. Done! 

    func getDigitsFromString(for string: String) -> [Int]{
        let stringInt = Array(string)
        var array = [Int]()
        for i in stringInt {
            if let i = Int(String(i)) {
                array.append(i)
            }
        }
        return array
    }
```