# Why am I getting the optional type 'String' error for user input collected by readLine()? How do I force a user to only enter data types I want?

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to write a function isIncreasing that will return true when the numbers in a list are in increasing order. First, I wrote var input = readLine() to get user input and applied isIncreasing directly to input. I received the error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'? In order to mute this error, I decided to apply the isIncreasing function only if the program knows for sure that input is an array of integers. However, even after I wrote the lines that convert user input into an array of integers, I still get the same error.

```
var result: Bool = true

func isIncreasing(_ num: [Int]) -> Bool{
    for i in num{
        if(num[i] < num[i + 1]){
            result = true
        }
        else{
            result = false
        }
    }
    return result
}

print("Type in a list of integers")
var input = readLine()

if (type(of: input) == type(of: "val")){ //changing types into [Int] to get rid of the optional type 'String' error
    var arg = [Int]()
    for element in input.characters
    //I am still gtting the error: swift:20:20: error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    {
        arg.append(Int(String(element))!)
    }
    isIncreasing(arg)
}
//var arg: [Int] = Array(input).map { String($0).toInt()! }
```

Comment: `if let input = readLine() {`

Comment: To convert the digits on a String to Int `let arg = input.compactMap{ $0.wholeNumberValue }`

Comment: Btw Why are you using Swift 3? Just update your Xcode to the newest version from the AppStore

Comment: If you really need Swift 3 code `let arg = input.compactMap { Int(String($0)) }` https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415964/2303865

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using swift 3 because I'm programming Swift on Windows, and I don't have access to a mac for now.