# How to add letters to an individual row in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm attempting to create 6 rows of 10 columns, with a individual letter attached to each row. In my particular case I want the first letter for the array to display, then the next and so on. As of now, only the first letter displays.

I'm not sure how to increment the column texts in the view itself to display a new letter for each row.

I attached an image below of the issue of what currently is happening.

```
struct CustomParent: View {
    @StateObject var customViewModel = CustomViewModel()
    
    let columnTexts = ["E", "A", "D", "G", "B", "E"] // << array
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           
            ForEach(0..<6, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
           
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text(columnTexts[rowIndex])
                    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { columnIndex in
                        let index = rowIndex * 10 + columnIndex
                        
                        if index < customViewModel.childTexts.count {
                            CustomChild(index: index, customViewModel: customViewModel)
                        } else {
                            Spacer()
                               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 20)
    }
}

struct CustomChild: View {
    let index: Int
    @ObservedObject var customViewModel: CustomViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            customViewModel.showNumberInputAlert(for: index)
            
            customViewModel.buttonPushed(at: index)
        }) {
           
            Text(customViewModel.childTexts[index])
                .frame(width: 20, height: 2)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
               // .border(.black)
        }
    }
}

class CustomViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var childTexts = [String](repeating: "", count: 10)
    @Published var fretSelected = false
    
    func showNumberInputAlert(for rowIndex: Int) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter a number", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { textField in
            textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        }
        
        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default) { _ in
            if let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text, let number = Int(text) {
               // Make changes here to text
                self.fretSelected = true
                self.childTexts[rowIndex] = String(number)
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(doneAction)
        
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    init() {
        for i in 0..<childTexts.count {
            if fretSelected {
                childTexts[i]
            }
            else{
                childTexts[i] = "__"
            }
           
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to draw a guitar fretboard ?

Comment: You are correct lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing :

```
let index = rowIndex * 10 + columnIndex
if index < customViewModel.childTexts.count {
   CustomChild(index: index, customViewModel: customViewModel)
} else {
   Spacer()
```

If I understand the code well we would not be able to display the customs childs of the second row as the index would be higher that the childTexts.count, are you sure the code you posted is accurate with the screen you posted?

Second thing, it would crash as you are giving "index" to childView but in the childView you are referencing an array of 10 elements

```
//In CustomChild:
 Text(customViewModel.childTexts[index]) //second row would give index 20 that cause outOfRange
```

Using a function to keep only the last digit of the "index" would be useful to avoid outOfRange and keep the real index in your childView [How to split an Int to its individual digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415937/how-to-split-an-int-to-its-individual-digits)

Third, after a minor fix on the code you posted I have the display you're seeking for.

```
// Please replace
if index < customViewModel.childTexts.count {
//with
if columnIndex < customViewModel.childTexts.count {

//In CustomChild
Text(customViewModel.childTexts[index])
//with
Text(customViewModel.childTexts[index.lastDigit]) //lastDigit would be a function from the StackOverlow resource I linked above
```

The edits I stated above are the only one I made to your code for it to obtain the result I'll post under:

[image]

EDIT: Something like this should do the job for the lastDigit function

```
extension Int {
    var lastDigit: Int {
        String(self).last!.wholeNumberValue!
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let index = 156
print(index.lastDigit) // should print 6
print(-4577.lastDigit) // should print -7
print(abs(-88).lastDigit) // should print 8
```

Note: I force unwrap as the functions `last` and `wholeNumberValue` cannot fail on a non-optionnal Int (if you want to work with optional Int I let you add some nil checking.)

Comment: Hey Any way you can show how you implemented the last digit function ?

Comment: @Swink I updated the original answer with a example of function to get the last digit.