# import a csv into a array of structs

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

**EDIT:** I needed to import a CSV (with string and integer column types) as an array of structs. ***Not*** as a 2D-array of structs (as nicely explained by answers).

**Original (poorly explained) question:**

I am trying to create a 2D array that contains string and integer values (based on the contents of a CSV that I have imported). These are identifiable by the "column" that they are in. Is there a way to accomplish this? I am aware of three possible solutions:

1. Declare the array as `[Any]` but I would prefer not to do this because I would like it to be explicitly typed
2. By using `.flatmap` (as in [How to convert a String (numeric) in a Int array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611336/how-to-convert-a-string-numeric-in-a-int-array-in-swift))

   let string = "123,456,789"
   let intArray = string.components(separatedBy: ",").flatMap { Int($0) }
   but I would prefer not to because I may have integers in a "String" column of my array.
3. Keep my array as a `[String]` and live with my "Int" column as a String (this is what I'm currently doing).

Below is a simplified version of the code I'm using. It errors when I try to parse my comma separated string into an Array with different value types.

All help is greatly appreciated... thank you!

```
struct MyStruct {
    let Str1 : String
    let Str2 : String
    let Str3 : String
    let Str4 : String
    let Int1 : Int
}

    func csvStringToArray(stringCSV: String) -> [[MyStruct]] {
        
        // create an empty 2-D array to hold the CSV data.
        var dataArray: [[MyStruct]] = []
        
        // parse the CSV into rows.
        var csvRows: [String] = stringCSV.components(separatedBy: "\n") 
       
        print(csvRows)
        // ["a,b,c,d,99", "j,k,l,m,98", "w,x,y,z,97", etc]

        // append each row (1-D array) to dataArray (filling the 2-D array).
        for i in csvRows {
            let csvColumns: [MyStruct] = i.components(separatedBy: ",") // Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to specified type '[MyStruct]'
            dataArray.append(csvColumns)
            print(csvColumns) // this is the output if I set csvColumns: [String]; otherwise it errors out.
            // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "99"]
            // ["j", "k", "l", "m", "98"]
            // ["w", "x", "y", "z", "97"]
            // etc...
        }
        print(dataArray) // again only if csvColumns: [String]
        // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "99"], ["j", "k", "l", "m", "98"], ["w", "x", "y", "z", "97"], [etc... ]

        return dataArray
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a CSV parsing library? For one, `components(separatedBy: ",")` will fail, by detecting all escaped commas (which must be parsed as part of a string, and not part of the CSV structure)

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a 3rd party library for simplicity sake. I know that my data will always follow the same format (I'm sure there are other issues, but the specific one you mentioned won't affect me). Would it still be better to use one even in this case?

Comment: I see nothing simple about reinventing the wheel over using what's already freely available. Requirements change, data formats change, so I wouldn't bother wasting my time writing a parser for such an incredibly limited subset of CSV.

Comment: Point taken. Further reflecting, I liked `components(separatedBy: ",")` because I could easily see how it worked. Having not used a library before, that seemed like more of a blackbox to me. One of the many things I need to get up to speed on.

Comment: Well then, that's definitely something to tackle. Black boxes are good. The more frequently you can produce well functioning code without the need to concern yourself with its internals, the better. Less is more.

Comment: A library might even use `components(separatedBy: ",")` internally, but it'll handle all the edge cases that one can easily miss. The escaped `,` was just one off the top of my head. Libraries benefit from having large user bases, whose use cases contribute to finding (and hopefully patching) edge cases the author might not have originally thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MyStruct` is already a structure for a row. Each element of `MyStruct` is a column. So ultimately your `dataArray` (the returning value for `func csvStringToArray(stringCSV: String)`) should be `[MyStruct]`, not `[[MyStruct]]`. Then your function becomes:

```
func csvStringToArray(stringCSV: String) -> [MyStruct] {

    // create an empty 2-D array to hold the CSV data.
    var dataArray: [MyStruct] = []

    // parse the CSV into rows.
    var csvRows: [String] = stringCSV.components(separatedBy: "\n") 

    print(csvRows)
    // ["a,b,c,d,99", "j,k,l,m,98", "w,x,y,z,97", etc]

    // append each row (1-D array) to dataArray (filling the 2-D array).
    for i in csvrows {
        let columns = i.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let csvColumns: MyStruct = MyStruct.init(Str1: columns[0], Str2: columns[1], Str3: columns[2], Str4: columns[3], Int1: 
        Int(columns[4])!)
        dataArray.append(csvColumns)
    }
    print(dataArray) 
    return dataArray
}
```

This is obviously assuming that your data types and structure are always valid (that your rows always have 4 strings and one integer for sure so they can be indexed or forced unwrapped), otherwise you will have to add checks for that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I only need one set of brackets around MyStruct for the returning value of the function because it's already set up to hold one dimension of elements. This made the error messages go away for me. If I use this method, am I forfeiting the ability to use subscripts on dataArray?

Comment: Nevermind my question. I was neglecting the entire reason for putting it into this structure. `dataArray[0].Int1` will return 99. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

As you noted in your comment, this line doesn't work:

```
let csvColumns: [MyStruct] = i.components(separatedBy: ",")
```

The `components(separatedBy:)` method always returns an array of Strings (`[String]`), so you can't set that value to a variable that is typed as an array of MyStruct (`[MyStruct]`).

It looks like your MyStruct type is supposed to represent a whole row of data (4 strings and an int), so I don't think it's correct to say a column is an array of MyStructs.  First reason being that these don't represent columns, but rows, and it seems like that 1 MyStruct == 1 row of values, and the data array would just be an array of those MyStruct row values (`[MyStruct]`) rather than an array of arrays of MyStruct instances (`[[MyStruct]]`) as you have it now.

That said, in order to most closely match what you have, I would suggest replacing MyStruct with a FieldValue enum that can hold either a String or an Int.  Using this approach, your code would look like this:

```
enum FieldValue {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)
}

func csvStringToArray(stringCSV: String) -> [[FieldValue]] {

    // create an empty 2-D array to hold the CSV data.
    var dataArray: [[FieldValue]] = []

    // parse the CSV into rows.
    var csvRows: [String] = stringCSV.components(separatedBy: "\n") 

    print(csvRows)
    // ["a,b,c,d,99", "j,k,l,m,98", "w,x,y,z,97", etc]

    // append each row (1-D array) to dataArray (filling the 2-D array).
    for i in csvRows {
        let csvRowValues: [FieldValue] = i.components(separatedBy: ",").map{
            if let value = Int($0) { 
                return FieldValue.int(value)
            }
            return FieldValue.string(value)
        }
    dataArray.append(csvRowValues)
    print(csvRowValues)
    print(dataArray) 
    return dataArray
}
```

Comment: After reading your & Santhosh's post I now understand exactly what you're saying about [[MyStruct]] vs [MyStruct]. Thank you for explaining that. With this method, if for example the 2nd element in a row was a string integer like "2" would it get converted to type Int also?

Comment: @user45392 Yes, each element gets parsed as a `FieldValue` which contains either an Int or a String. You would unwrap them when ready to use them like this:  `switch fieldValue { case .int(let int): /*do something with the Int value int*/ case .string(let string): /*do something with the String value string*/ }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the conversion to be fully typed and avoid `Any`, try this approach:

```
struct MyDataType {

  struct Row {

    enum DataPoint {
      case string(String)
      case integer(Int)

      init?(stringValue: String) {
        guard !stringValue.isEmpty else { return nil }

        if let integerValue = Int(stringValue) {
          self = .integer(integerValue)
        } else {
          self = .string(stringValue)
        }
      }
    }

    let dataPoints: [DataPoint]

    init?(csv: String) {
      let components = csv.components(separatedBy: ",")
      guard !components.isEmpty else { return nil }

      dataPoints = components.flatMap(DataPoint.init)
    }
  }

  let rows: [Row]

  init?(csv: String) {
    let csvRows = csv.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    guard !csvRows.isEmpty else { return nil }

    rows = csvRows.flatMap(Row.init)
  }
}


// Example usage.

let csvString = """
123,134,a,65,4,bc
43,53,t,4,5,1
a,3,e,12,u,50
"""

//  Force unrwapping here, because we know `csvString` is valid csv.
//  You should not force unwrap generally.
let data = MyDataType(csv: csvString)!

if let firstRow = data.rows.first {

  print("First rows content:")

  for (idx, dataPoint) in firstRow.dataPoints.enumerated() {
    let descriptor: String

    switch dataPoint {
    case .string(let stringValue):
      descriptor = "String: \(stringValue)"
    case .integer(let integerValue):
      descriptor = "Integer: \(integerValue)"
    }

    print("[\(idx)] > \(descriptor)")
    /*
     Prints:


     First rows content:
     [0] > Integer: 123
     [1] > Integer: 134
     [2] > String: a
     [3] > Integer: 65
     [4] > Integer: 4
     [5] > String: bc
     */
  }
}
```

Explanation:

- `MyDataType` represents all of the imported csv data.
- `Row` represents a single row in the imported csv data.
- `DataPoint` can hold either a `String` or an `Int`. Note that this is quite similar to how `Optional<T>` works.
- Each `MyDataType` has multiple `Row`s.
- Each `Row` has multiple `DataPoint`s.
- `MyDataType`, `Row` and `DataPoint` declare initialisers that can parse their respective portion of the csv string. Some safeguards are added to check for empty strings, but that is implementation dependent.

---

### Update

Given some more context in the comments, this is how you would extend the generic solution provided above and enforce a specific csv format:

```
extension MyDataType.Row {
  init?(enforcingCustomFormatOn csv: String) {
    let components = csv.components(separatedBy: ",")
    guard components.count == 5 else { return nil }

    dataPoints = components.enumerated().flatMap { idx, stringValue in
      switch idx {
        //  Enforcing .string in the first 4 columns
      case 0..<4: return .string(stringValue)
      default: return DataPoint(stringValue: stringValue)
      }
    }
  }
}

extension MyDataType {
  init?(enforcingCustomFormatOn csv: String) {
    let csvRows = csv.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    guard !csvRows.isEmpty else { return nil }

    rows = csvRows.flatMap(Row.init(enforcingCustomFormatOn:))
  }
}
```

You can now simply use `init(enforcingCustomFormatOn:)` and columns 1-4 will be treated as string values. Only column 5 will be converted to .integer if possible.

Note that you would need to change `rows = csvRows.flatMap(Row.init)` in `MyDataType.init(csv:)` to `rows = csvRows.flatMap(Row.init(csv:))`. Otherwise, `.flatMap` will not know which init to pick, because both have the same signature.

Comment: Yup. Changed that. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, Cabus. The detailed explanation is extremely helpful even though I used the method from Santhosh this time (I know my data will always adhere to a very strict format). Your method would convert integers sitting any in a row (not just the 5th column), right? I would need to keep anything not in the 5th column as a String, even if it looks like an integer.